# Как изменить заголовок на панели действий?

Tags: java, android

Пробовал

```
    String title;
    if (position == 0) {
        title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    } else {
        title = titles[position];
    }
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

Но выходит ошибка:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at
>   com.example.anonym.bitandpizza.MainActivity.setActionBarTitle(MainActivity.java:77)

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Comment: Более того можно просто использовать метод setTitle(title), без вызова getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в своем проекте используете `AppCompat`, тогда обращаться к ActionBar'у так:

```
getSupportActionBar()
```